# Is $L^\infty(X, \mu)$ dual of $L^1(X, \mu)$ if X is discrete

Tags: measure-theory

Is $L^\infty(X, \mu)$ dual of $L^1(X, \mu)$  if X is discrete and $\mu$ is not finite?

Like, if X = {x,y} and $\mu({x}) = 1$ and $\mu({y}) = \infty $, then $L^\infty(X, \mu)$ is not dual of $L^1(X, \mu)$ since, Let $f(x) =  1$ and $f(y) = 0$ And I can define a linear operator to $\mathbb R$ by $ x*f(x) + y*f(y)$ but there is no element in $L^\infty(X, \mu)$ which can represent this.

Am I right?

Comment: I think these duality of $L_p$ results always include the hypothesis that the measure is sigma-finite.  Your example explains why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your $X$ and $\mu$, the problem is not that $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is too small, but rather that it is too big.

Because $L^\infty(X,\mu)=\mathbb C\oplus\mathbb C$ regardless of what $\mu$ is. While $L^1(X,\mu)=\mathbb C\oplus 0$. As the dual of a finite-dimensional vector space has its same dimension, $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is too big to be the dual of $L^1(X,\mu)$ (it does contain the dual, though).

Comment: Why $L^\infty$ is 2 dimensional? The step maps are one dimensional so isn't its $L^\infty$ completion is also 1 dimensional?

Comment: You don't define $L^\infty$ in terms of step functions; $L^\infty$ is simply the set of (a.e.) uniformly bounded measurable functions on $X$. Here the set of all functions on $X$ is $\mathbb C^2$, and every one of these functions is measurable and unformly bounded.

Comment: Yup got it thanks.

Comment: This necessarily means my proof in the question is wrong :)

Comment: In this case, $L^{\infty}\subset (L^1)^*$ just by multiplication. However, $L^{\infty}$ is not isomorphism to $(L^1)^*$

Comment: @LiJingyang: you cannot write an inclusion because it is not an embedding. The map that takes $f\in L^\infty$ to the left multiplier in $(L^1)^*$ is not one-to-one, as I mention in my answer (for example, $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ give the same multiplier, because for $L^1$ only the first coordinate matters. ).

Comment: yes, my "inclusion" is wrong. I just want to clarify that $L^{\infty}$ is not too big.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not too big": in the OP's example, the dual of $L^1$ has dimension one, and $L^\infty$ has dimension two.